# Is it possible to toggle XMonad.Hooks.EwmhDesktops.fullscreenEventHook?

Tags: haskell, xmonad

Im using Xmonad as a window manager. To automatically handle fullscreen window i use XMonad.Hooks.EwmhDesktops.fullscreenEventHook. And put this in my config:

```hs
        , handleEventHook = handleEventHook def <+> docksEventHook <+> XMonad.Hooks.EwmhDesktops.fullscreenEventHook
```

I would like the ability to toggle this with a keybind. So by default the fullscreen window takes up the entire screen, but when i toggle EwmhDesktops.fullscreenEventHook off it is only fullscreen in the "tiled" space the window takes up.

Full config is [here](https://gitlab.com/Syslak/dotfiles/-/blob/master/.xmonad/xmonad.hs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very hard to add state into XMonad itself, so we'll have to use [`IORef`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Data-IORef.html) for external state. First, we'll make a fullscreen event hook that checks a boolean from an IORef and only runs the actual event hook if it's true:

```hs
toggleableFullscreen :: IORef Bool -> Event -> X All
toggleableFullscreen ref evt =
    io (readIORef ref) >>= \isOn ->
        if isOn
            then XMonad.Hooks.EwmhDesktops.fullscreenEventHook evt
            else return (All True)
```

This uses [`io :: IO a -> X a`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-0.15/docs/XMonad-Core.html#v:io) to lift an `IO` monad into an `X` monad. Now, in our main function, we want to construct the `IORef` with [`newIORef`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Data-IORef.html):

```hs
main = do
    fullscreenRef <- newIORef True -- default to being on
    -- rest of main goes here
```

Now, we'll also edit the `handleEventHook` line of main to use our `toggleableFullscreen` with the `fullscreenRef` passed in:

```hs
, handleEventHook = handleEventHook def <+> docksEventHook <+> toggleableFullscreen fullscreenRef
```

So, that's the event hook part done. Now we need a way to toggle it. The `myKeys` function needs to take in the `fullscreenRef` as a parameter as well, so you have to add it in:

```hs
myKeys fullscreenRef conf@(XConfig {XMonad.modMask = modm}) = M.fromList $
    -- rest of myKeys
```

(this is on line 125 of your config)

Then, you have to add a new keybinding (let's say mod+shift+f) that toggles the IORef using `modifyIORef`:

```hs
, ((modm .|. shiftMask, xK_f), io (modifyIORef fullscreenRef not))
```

Then, in your main function, pass `fullscreenRef` into `myKeys`:

```hs
, keys = myKeys fullscreenRef
```

(line 400)

And remove this entire chunk since you don't use it (and it won't typecheck):

```hs
defaults = def {
      -- simple stuff
        terminal           = myTerminal,
        focusFollowsMouse  = myFocusFollowsMouse,
        clickJustFocuses   = myClickJustFocuses,
        borderWidth        = myBorderWidth,
        modMask            = myModMask,
        workspaces         = myWorkspaces,
        normalBorderColor  = myNormalBorderColor,
        focusedBorderColor = myFocusedBorderColor,

      -- key bindings
        keys               = myKeys,
        mouseBindings      = myMouseBindings,

      -- hooks, layouts
        layoutHook         = myLayout,
        manageHook         = myManageHook,
        handleEventHook    = myEventHook,
        logHook            = myLogHook,
        startupHook        = myStartupHook
    }
```

(lines 446-467)

Then, restart xmonad and you should be able to toggle your fullscreen event hook with mod+shift+f.

Comment: I was not able to get this to work. I get the following error:
"
    Not in scope: type constructor or class 'All'
    toggleableFullscreen ::IORef Bool -> Event -> X All
"
With my very little knowledge of haskell I have yet to figure out how to get it working.

Comment: If you [search for All on hoogle](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=All), you'll find that you have to import either Data.Monoid or Data.Semigroup.